# SELECT QUERY structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query I am hoping to shorten.

```
SELECT date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6, date7 FROM dates_db 
WHERE date1 =('$date1') OR date1 =('$date2') OR date1=('$date3') 
OR date1=('$date4') OR date1=('$date5') OR date1=('$date6') 
OR date1=('$date7') OR date2 =('$date1') OR date2 =('$date2') 
OR date2=('$date3') OR date2=('$date4') OR date2=('$date5')
OR date2=('$date6') OR date2=('$date7') OR date3 =('$date1') 
OR date3 =('$date2')OR date3=('$date3') OR date3=('$date4') 
OR date3=('$date5') OR date3=('$date6') OR date3=('$date7')
```

and so on for date 1-7 .

This query is massive, is there any way of shortening it. This is for a calender type design where it is looking for data entries that are in different days. So if a date matches then it will post it to the calendar.

Comment: You should normalize your database, to avoid doing this crazy stuff.

Comment: the actual database is holiday_db and has many fields like name, etc.. just includes 7 dates for people too book off work.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here but even if you use IN to find the value within a range inside the query this doesn't look efficient. Is your dates_db populated purely with dates in a range you wish to use? If so might you be better looking at the php functions such as strftime rather than having a table of dates?

Comment: it is not just a table of dates @codepuppy this was to speed up help. People book time off work, this table holds the dates, their name, why they are off etc...

Comment: I think i know what you meant now, I have changed my look on it. Still using `IN` but differently structured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `IN` predicate instead of these `OR`'s like so:

```
SELECT date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6, date7
FROM dates_db 
WHERE date1 IN ('$date1','$date2','$date3','$date4','$date5','$date6','$date7')
  OR  date2 IN ('$date1','$date2','$date3','$date4','$date5','$date6','$date7')
  OR  date3 IN ('$date1','$date2','$date3','$date4','$date5','$date6','$date7')
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 SELECT date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6, date7 FROM dates_db 
 WHERE date1 IN ('$date1','$date2',...) OR date2 IN('$date1','$date2',...)....
```

Or,

```
$dates = $date1.",".$date2.",".$date3.",".........;
 SELECT date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6, date7 FROM dates_db 
 WHERE date1 IN ('$dates') OR date2 IN('$dates').....
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you will use `IN`

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE   date1 IN ('$date1','$date2','$date3','$date4','$date5','$date6','$date7') OR
        date2 IN ('$date1','$date2','$date3','$date4','$date5','$date6','$date7') OR
        date3 IN ('$date1','$date2','$date3','$date4','$date5','$date6','$date7')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that involves only listing the `$date` variables once.  Some modification may be needed for MySQL syntax:

```
WITH search_dates (date) as (
     values ('$date1'),('$date2'),...
)
SELECT DISTINCT date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6, date7 FROM dates_db 
    INNER JOIN search_dates ON 
        date1 = date OR
        date2 = date OR ...
        date7 = date;
```

In an ideal world, your `dates_db` table would also be structured differently, so that each row only contains one date.